# How can I use this code on a custom database table?

Tags: custom-post-types, columns

I have a custom database table that contains some data. At the moment, I just want to display an overview of the values contained in the table in WordPress Admin area.

```
add_filter('manage_mycustom_posts_columns', array($this, 'xxx_columns_head'));
add_action('manage_mycustom_posts_custom_column', array($this, 'xxx_columns_content'));

public function xxx_columns_content($column_name) {
    global $post;
    $post_ID = $post->ID;
    $values = $this->xxxx_get_cpt_data($post_ID);
    //print_r($values);
}

public function xxxx_get_cpt_data($post_ID) {
    $cpt_values = get_post_custom($post_ID);
    if ($cpt_values) {
        return $cpt_values;
    }
}
```

I realize I can't use the function `get_post_custom()` and the `$post_ID` isn't used in my custom table. So how can I make a function `xxx_get_post_custom(...)` so that I can populate the overview values?

[edit]

```
    public function xxxx_get_cpt_data() {
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM custom_table";
    $cpt_values = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
    //print_r($cpt_values);
    if ($cpt_values) {
              return $cpt_values->column_name;
         }else {
              return ' ';  
         }

}
```

And for the columns contents:

```
public function xxxx_columns_content($column_name) {

        $values = $this->xxxx_get_cpt_data();
        print_r($values);//

      foreach ($values as $value) {
        //print_r($value[0]);
        $value = $value[0];
            if ($column_name == 'name') {
                $name = isset($value['name']) ? esc_attr($value['name'][0]) : '';
                echo $name;
            }
.....other columns content
        }
  }

}
```

But now I get all database table content for each column, all in one row.

Comment: You may run any query you desire with [wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) class. Normally `custom_post_meta` is saved in `{$dbPrefix}_postmeta` table. You may use filters to reroute functionality on all meta related functions, but since I never needed to, my experience with this ends here. I recommend [this read](http://sltaylor.co.uk/blog/custom-meta-tables-wordpress/).

Comment: In the majority of cases, custom post types, custom taxonomies, or custom post meta are a better choice. The prime use case of custom database tables is integrating with other software and CMS'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes  you have to write a custom function and call it  on your manage columns it will help you to get the necessary contents.

```
     public function xxxx_get_cpt_data($post_ID) {
          //        $cpt_values = get_post_custom($post_ID);
           global $wpdb;

             $sql = "SELECT * FROM ". $wpdb->prefix. "custom_table WHERE post_ID=". $post_ID. " LIMIT 1" ;
              $cpt_values = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
            if ($cpt_values) {
                  return $cpt_values->column_name;
             }else {
                  return ' ';  
             }
       }
```

But the `get_results` returns an array of objects.  If you wish to get a single result than use `get_var`. 
If you have multiple values on the custom table go with `get_results` use it like this `$obj->coulmn_name;`